# Ionic screen went blank when trying to use REST service

Tags: angular, rest, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am currently trying to use RESTful service in Ionic.

I imported the REST service on the pages that needed it and also the method to retrieve user from database.

However, after I typed and saved the method and imports all, my ionic lab mobile screen is blank. I tried to undo all my codes but the mobile screen remains blank.

May I know why?

My `app.module.ts`

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { RestProvider } from '../providers/rest/rest';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    RestProvider
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

My REST provider `rest.ts`

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class RestProvider {

  apiUrl = '';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
  }

  getUsers() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/users').subscribe(data => {
      resolve(data);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
}

}
```

My homepage `home.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, MenuController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RestProvider } from '../../providers/rest/rest';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage{

  users: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public menuCtrl: MenuController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public restProvider: RestProvider) {
      this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.restProvider.getUsers()
    .then(data => {
      this.users = data;
      console.log(this.users);
    });
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {

       this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable( false )
   }

   ionViewDidLeave() {

       this.menuCtrl.swipeEnable( true )
   }

}
```

Comment: Do you have restprovider in your module ? Pd: you can use toPromise() after suscribe instead of a new promise

Comment: @saescudero sorry i don't really get what you mean. i imported it in my app.module.ts, is it not that?

Comment: Yes, it is. Some errors in the console ?

Comment: Remember when you use resolve(data) it’s not a json!.

Comment: @saescudero yeah, whenever i run my app, it shows this error `Module '"C:/.....rxjs/Rx"' has no exported member 'SubscriptionLike'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using Visual Studio's emulator will cause this issue. Using external emulators such as your own device will not cause such issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use toPromise method from rxjs:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

getUsers() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/users')
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => data.json())
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```